# Xcode doesn't autobuild new files

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to add a new class to my project on xcode.
The problem is that xcode doesn't auto complete anything when typing in that class, auto build anything or anything else for that matter.
When ignoring the auto complete, and typing myself, I later try to link my xib file to my class by "pulling the strings" and when I hit enter I get the notorious error message in red saying "could not insert outlet - could not find any information on class..."
I have tried deleting the Derived Data folder, restart xcode, deleting the files of the class I was trying to add, etc. Nothing worked. 
What do I do?
I think I have an issue with linking - if I try to add the interface for the xib file, which I created to have a custom table row view, in an existing file already in the project, it all works wonders.
Any one see that problem before?

Thanks!

Comment: Make sure the new header files are at the targets headers search path and the new implementation files are added to the targets compilation stage. Xcode can be used as a text editor with the files completely unrelated to the project, you could have put these files at the project folder too.

Answer (score 0):

Choose the m file in your left panel, then choose the target in the right panel.If you already add the file to the target, then in your project build settings, set the search path to your folders. May be the folder that files locate is not the real file filer, it is just a group.

Comment: Apparently, the only problem was that I had to choose Cocoa Touch Class, instead of a clear m/h file under Source for iOS apps when creating a new class...go figure